# iterate over formatted JSON Array

Tags: javascript, sql

I am querying an MS SQL Database, which is returning a formatted JSON Array. Below is an example of what is returned. I have used just about every JavaScript  example I can find to iterate over the array, but nothing is working:

```
[
  [
    {"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},
    {"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},
    {"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}
  ]
]
```

Comment: Care to show every example you've tried, please?

Comment: This is an invalid JSON input

Comment: @GillesQuenot OP says it's output, so it may be safe to assume the missing quote is a typo? But good catch

Comment: @Hans - John's issue with this could be the invalid json due to the missing quote, it could be the array of arrays and it could be forgetting to parse it, since the sql return will be a string. Correcting the json in the question changes the question.

Comment: Show code (tried) and get help with that code.

Comment: the following is a print out of the formatted JSON array that is being returned from an SQL Database:[
  [
    {"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},
    {"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},
    {"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}
  ]
]                                       I need to access the data but the returned data has extra brackets. I need help iterating over this to extract the information

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your json array there that will need to be solved first

1. You have a `"` missing on Sunday
2. You have an array of arrays, not just an array.

When your array is correct the return from your SQL should look like this:

`'[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},{"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}]'`

That isn't a json object yet, it's just a string that looks like one, to make use of that as a json object/array you need to parse it like this:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},{"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}]');
```

If you can't get around the `[[]]` array within an array, you can handle it like this:

```
var jsonOuterArray = JSON.parse('[[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},{"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}]]');
var jsonArray = jsonOuterArray[0];
```

With that there are many ways to iterate over it in javascript, it all depends what libraries you use and what you want to get out of it, like how the jQuery example give not only the object but the position in the array for that object but the forEach will not.

For each example, `jsonArray` will be the parsed out json from your SQL, `key` will be the position in the array and `value` will be the object in the array.

JavaScript: (array prototype forEach)

```
jsonArray.forEach(function(value){
    console.log(value.id, value.Title)
});
```

JavaScript: (for loop)

```
for (var key = 0; key < jsonArray.length; key++) {
    var value = jsonArray[key];
    console.log(value.id, value.Title)
};
```

jQuery:

```
$.each(jsonArray, function (key, value){
    console.log(value.id, value.Title)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using nodejs (ES5 syntax) :

```
> [[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"}, {"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}]][0]
.forEach(function(elt){ console.log(elt.id, elt.Title)})
1 'Friday'
2 'Saturday'
3 'Sunday'
```

Comment: forEach doesn't need node, it's part of the array prototype.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but I just clarify that i use nodejs... Don't understand the down vote

Comment: Wasn't from me, your code would work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a quote is missing before **Sunday**:

```
[[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},    {"id":3,"Title":Sunday"}]]
```

therefore you will not be able to evaluate this JSON. Assuming that the JSON is corrected to

```
[[{"id":1,"Title":"Friday"},{"id":2,"Title":"Saturday"},    {"id":3,"Title":"Sunday"}]]
```

you will be able to iterate it in conventional manners, using a `for` cycle, for example.